# Postgresql Logger Process

Tags: postgresql, logging

I'm trying to determine if Postgres 9.3 still has a logger process.  It isn't referenced anywhere in the "PostgreSQL 9.3.4 Documentation".  And I can't find it in my cluster's process list (see below).  Also, does anyone know of a good general overview the memory structures in 9.3?

```
postgres 21397     1  0 20:51 pts/1    00:00:00 /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/postgres
postgres 21399 21397  0 20:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
postgres 21400 21397  0 20:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
postgres 21401 21397  0 20:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
postgres 21402 21397  0 20:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres 21403 21397  0 20:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: archiver process last was 0001000004000092
postgres 21404 21397  0 20:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
```

Thanks
Jim

Comment: Ken's covered the main question. Please try not to add "also"s and multi-questions; it makes it hard to have a single definitive answer to a question. As for "memory structures": the source code is what you need to look at. If you mean the *on-disk format* or *wire protocol*, those are documented in the user manual. (Upvoted anyway because it's a clear and comprehensible 1st question with *versions specified* - we like that!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Postgres* has a *logging collector* process which is controlled through a config parameter, 
**logging_collector**.

So in your *postgresql.conf* file, you would make sure this is set:

> logging_collector = on

The blurb on this param from the *postgres* doc:

> This parameter enables the logging collector, which is a background
>   process that captures log messages sent to stderr and redirects them
>   into log files. This approach is often more useful than logging to
>   syslog, since some types of messages might not appear in syslog
>   output. (One common example is dynamic-linker failure messages;
>   another is error messages produced by scripts such as
>   archive_command.) This parameter can only be set at server start.

It will show up in the process list with the following description:

> postgres: logger process

For more info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Regarding the memory structures, I'm not sure offhand, but would recommend you post that as a separate question.